# ReduxForm: passing initialValues from mapStatetoProps

Tags: redux, redux-form

I'm trying to get the initialValues of the form setup as follows but it doesn't work:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  initialValues: state.charts[props.resourceId],
});

const mapDispatchToProps = ...

export default reduxForm({ 
  form: 'ChartForm',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChartForm));
```

Of course if I do something like this will work:

```
export default reduxForm({ 
      form: 'ChartForm',
      initialValues: {
          title: "Some Title",
          ...
      }
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChartForm));
```

That is not what I need though. I need to get the initial values from a resource in my store that has `id == this.props.resourceId`

Could anybody point out what is wrong with the first solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the `initialValues` props into the form. To do that wrap the form with the connect function. See [Initialize From State](https://redux-form.com/7.1.0/examples/initializefromstate/) in the documentation.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({ 
  form: 'ChartForm',
})(ChartForm));
```

Comment: For all those wondering as for today 2019. you need enableReinitialize: true as part of the redux form options. If you don't pass it, the form won't be re-rendered once the props arrive asynchronous